# Retrospective survival analysis censoring

Tags: survival, cox-model, censoring, kaplan-meier

I'm doing a retrospective survival analysis where I evaluate the recurrence of disease after surgery. The problem is that some of the patients don't come again to the clinic after surgery to do the follow-up visits and some others are followed up, for example, for less than 1 month (it should be noted that the disease usually recurs 2 months after the surgery). Taking this into account, should I include them both and consider them as right-censored data or should I delete them from my database?

Answer (score 3):

*All* survival analyses are retrospective. It's the study design which may be prospective or retrospective. The design, it turns out, has no impact on the censoring because our approach to information accrual in a longitudinal study is always prospective. Conditioning on the future will affect the analyses negatively.

This seems to be an incomplete description of the data analysis. Among many things, you're missing a description of the censoring rules. These are analysis dependent, but you can borrow heavily from the literature on cancer studies and endpoints. In almost all studies of progression-free survival, the censoring timepoint is the last evaluable scan (if available) or else to study day 1.

The reason to censor subjects at study day 1 is a formality. Censoring values at study day 1 is identical to removing them from analyses if there are no events at study day 1. (If events occur at day 1, you need to take a different approach such as finding the *time* of events, and censoring subjects at the 1 *minute* mark).

Subjects who attend the 1-month follow-up and are shown to be disease free can be censored at the 1-month mark. This is a proven a simple method to handle the issue of interval censoring - that is that even though disease recurrence occurs between two scanning time points, the event occurrence is taken to be the timepoint at which the scan provided evidence of disease recurrence (even though it most likely happened earlier). Subjects who miss multiple scanning intervals may be censored if the interval is too long to reasonably say the disease recurrence occurred at this time. The incidence of disease is biased negatively. Note, you can't just consider the event to have happened earlier because you would be conditioning on the future.

I am assuming in this case that you are using a Cox proportional hazards model for the outcome.